# GIT recognize file as new when modifying key value using python in windows

Tags: python, json, git, bitbucket, pull-request

I have python code which modify key value in json file:

```
with open(filename_write, 'r') as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

data['test']['ariel']['version'] = value

with open(filename_write, 'w') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4)
```

But when I crating PR in bitbucket, it shows the file as new instead of showing only the diff I did. any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: top suspect: the original doesn't have the same sequence or linebreaks/whitespace as the dumped version.

Comment: my even topper suspect ;) : you are working on windows or Mac and have a case difference in the filename

Comment: working in windows, file name is the same

Comment: Got an actual [mcve] so folks on Windows can see this behaviour happening?